# Раскрытие (сворачивание) меню

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, веб-программирование

Есть сайт с раскрывающимися подменю (боковая стрелка имеет направление вниз - класс `arrow_01_B` (раскрытое подменю) или имеет направление вправо - `arrow_01_R` (свернутое подменю))

[image: Вид сайта]

Привожу код для раскрытия/сворачивания меню

```js
let elemsoffilteropengroup = document.querySelectorAll('.FilterDropdown__filter-open-group');

for (let i = 0; i < elemsoffilteropengroup.length; i++) {
  elemsoffilteropengroup[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.childNodes[1].classList.contains('arrow_01_R')) {
      firstProperty = 'FilterDropdown__toggle-opened';
      secondProperty = 'arrow_01_B';
      lastProperty = 'IconFont_arrow_01_B';
      e.target.childNodes[1].classList.item(0) = firstProperty;
      e.target.childNodes[1].classList.item(1) = secondProperty;
      e.target.childNodes[1].classList.item(e.target.childNodes[1].classList.length - 1) = lastProperty;
    } else {
      firstProperty = 'FilterDropdown__toggle-closed';
      secondProperty = 'arrow_01_R';
      lastProperty = 'IconFont_arrow_01_R';
      e.target.childNodes[1].classList.item(0) = firstProperty;
      e.target.childNodes[1].classList.item(1) = secondProperty;
      e.target.childNodes[1].classList.item(e.target.childNodes[1].classList.length - 1) = lastProperty;
    }
  }, true);
}
```

Несмотря на наличие этого кода меню не разворачивается (не сворачивается). Подскажите как добиться разворачивания\сворачивания меню.

**P.S.**

1. А div.FilterDropdown__filter-open-group включает в себя заголовок (как на рисунке Основной цвет корпуса) и стрелку для раскрытия\сворачивания меню.
2. target-ом должен быть элемент  - стрелка раскрытия\сворачивания меню и обращение к нему происходит через `childNodes[1]`.
3. Классы меняются для смены вида стрелок.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте этот код. Протестировать не могу, потому что не предоставлен рабочий пример, поэтому могут быть ошибки. Ну и не знаю какие браузеры целевые, так что подгоните под нужные.

```
let elemsOfFilterOpenGroup = document.querySelectorAll('.FilterDropdown__filter-open-group');

Array.from(elemsOfFilterOpenGroup).forEach( element => {
    element.addEventListener( 'click', clickHandler );
});

function clickHandler(){
    let arrow = this.querySelector('i'),
        openedClasses = ['FilterDropdown__toggle-opened','arrow_01_B','IconFont_arrow_01_B'],
        closedClasses = ['FilterDropdown__toggle-closed','arrow_01_R','IconFont_arrow_01_R'];
    
    if( arrow.classList.contains('arrow_01_R') ){
        arrow.classList.remove(...closedClasses);
        arrow.classList.add(...openedClasses);
    } else {
        arrow.classList.remove(...openedClasses);
        arrow.classList.add(...closedClasses);
    }
}
```

Comment: см. https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/ (я брал интерфейс оттуда). Правда я там не нашел класса `arrow_01_R` (нашел только `IconFont_arrow_01_R`).

Comment: Мне смотреть какой-то сайт и самому что-то из него выковыривать смысла нет. Просто попробуйте этот код. Сработает хорошо, нет так нет. Вы же зачем-то пример кода привели.

Comment: я внутрь `clickHandler` поместил первым  отладочный оператор `alert('Hi, user')`. В результате не сработало.

Comment: Алертами никто не отлаживает код. Не бывает "не сработало". Должно быть "проверил что найдены элементы, проверил установку на них слушателей, проверил срабатывание обработчика...", всё через консоль браузера. Иначе никогда ничего работать не будет по какой-то волшебной причине.

Comment: см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1265945/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8e

Comment: Не известно куда и когда вы вставляете код. Любое предположение требует проверки, а по картинке страницы не проверишь ничего.